# Single responsibility principle and Sharepoint WebParts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a big number of webparts for a Sharepoint project.  Many of them have the same parameters, and / or the same WebPart connections.

I tried to apply the SRP to this case, but I was unable, because the class has to expose some methods.

How can one overcome this in this case, and make a better design for the webparts code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **excellent** resource for best practices and design patterns designed for medium-to-large scale SharePoint projects is the [patterns & practices SharePoint Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/spg). This has been put together by SharePoint MVPs as well as Microsoft.

Study this thoroughly and you will get a lot out of how to architect and structure SharePoint solutions!